# Doctrine 1.2: How do i prevent a contraint from being assigned to both sides of a One-to-many relation?

Tags: symfony1, doctrine, foreign-key-relationship, one-to-one

Is there a way to prevent Doctrine from assigning a contraint on both sides of a one-to-one relationship? Ive tried moving the definition from one side to the other and using owning side but it still places a constraint on both tables. when I only want the parent table to have a constraint - ie. its possible for the parent to not have an associated child.

For example iwant the following sql schema essentially:

```
CREATE TABLE `parent_table` (
  `child_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `child_table` (
  `id` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `child_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`child_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `parent_table_child_id_FK_child_table_child_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`child_id`)
    REFERENCES `parent_table` (`child_id`)
);
```

However im getting something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE `parent_table` (
  `child_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  `id` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  CONSTRAINT `child_table_child_id_FK_parent_table_child_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`child_id`)
    REFERENCES `child_table` (`child_id`)
);

CREATE TABLE `child_table` (
  `id` integer UNSIGNED NOT NULL auto_increment,
  `child_id` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE KEY (`child_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `parent_table_child_id_FK_child_table_child_id`
    FOREIGN KEY (`child_id`)
    REFERENCES `parent_table` (`child_id`)
);
```

I could just remove the constraint manually or modify my accessors to return/set a single entity in the collection (using a one-to-many) but it seems like there should built in way to handle this.

Also im using Symfony 1.4.4 (pear installtion ATM) - in case its an sfDoctrinePlugin issue and not necessarily Doctrine itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

sfDoctrinePlugin configures doctrine model builder in way that creates opposite side relations automatically. In PHP 5.2 you can't do anything with it.

As of PHP 5.3, where [`ReflectionProperty::setAccessible()` method](http://www.php.net/manual/en/reflectionproperty.setaccessible.php) is available, [you could manipulate protected/private properties](http://schlitt.info/opensource/blog/0581_reflecting_private_properties.html) of `Doctrine_Relation_Parser` instance which can be obtained by `$this->getTable()->getRelationParser()`. So you have to override `BaseSomething::setUp()` method and drop unneeded relations manually using php's reflection API. You have to use reflection API because `Doctrine_Relation_Parser` doesn't provide a method which allows to drop relations at will.

Comment: So it is specific to Symfony and not Doctrine? I ask because im doing some rapid prototyping in symfony for this but the final app will be developed/written in Zend. So if this isnt an issue with Doctrine in general i just need to find a workaround for them moment - if its actually Doctrine that has the issue then ill have to do something more involved.

Comment: Well, it's nor Doctrine issue, nor even an issue — it's just a configuration parameter.

Comment: can someone pl throw light on this?

Even after this dual relation mess, Im gettin an error that says, Add method does not exist for the child relation. this is killing me!!!

Answer (score 1):

I've solved this by setting the doctrine state for the opposite "null object" **BEFORE** we save the record:

```
/* @var $address Address */
$address = $form->getObject();

// the null object is here the "address position", let's change it's state
$address->getAddressPosition()->state(Doctrine_Record::STATE_CLEAN);

// now we can save the address and doctrine won't insert the null object
$address = $form->save();
```