# Prevent Doctrine 1 creating foreign key constraints

Tags: php, doctrine

Is it possible to prevent doctrine 1.2 from adding foreign key constraints for a relation?

Comment: related : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2623941/doctrine-1-2-how-do-i-prevent-a-contraint-from-being-assigned-to-both-sides-of-a

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you are going to use MYISAM then just do this in your model:

```
public function setUp() {
        $this->option('type', 'MyISAM');
}
```

Comment: you can also specify it in schema.yml for all models by adding these lines at the top: 
options:
  type: MyISAM